# Adding custom actions to rosbuild

Tags: arduino, rosserial, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a package defining messages for [rosserial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial). After changing a message, I need to deploy (copy) the changes to a folder containing generated messages for an Arduino board. Is there a (clean) way to add custom actions to the rosbuild system? For now I'm assuming I could modify Makefile in my message-defining-package adding the actions I need after the call:

```
include $(shell rospack find mk)/cmake.mk
```

but won't it get overwritten in some case and is it the right way to do it? I've got a deploy script and would like to call it from somewhere.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11146/adding-custom-actions-to-rosbuild/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-09-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure that it's the correct answer, but I think you should rather edit the CMakeLists.txt than the Makefile.

You can add a custom command to your CMakeLists.txt using this line:

```
EXECUTE_PROCESS(COMMAND "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/your_script.sh")
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-09-08**:
Actually I just tested it again to make sure and executing make on my message-package causes correct behaviour, ie. all generated messages get copied after being built. I added my deploy script at the end of CMakeLists.txt.

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-09-08**:
Note that `execute_process()` will run in-place when the CMakeLists.txt file is parsed, before the build happens.  If you would rather arrange for the command to run later, during/after the build, see my answer on using `add_custom_target()`.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-09-07**:
Yes, it surely will - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `add_custom_target()`, e.g.:

```
# Declare a custom target that will do the copy when the 'all' target fires
add_custom_target(deploy ALL
                  COMMAND cp $(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/undeployed /tmp/deployed)
# Declare a dependency on the 'rosbuild_precompile' target, to ensure 
# that message generation happens before we copy.
add_dependencies(deploy rosbuild_precompile)
```

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2